# Perl - How do I update (and access) an array stored in array stored in a hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

Perhaps I have made this more complicated than I need it to be but I am currently trying to store an array that contains, among other things, an array inside a hash in Perl.

i.e. hash -> array -> array

```
use strict;

my %DEVICE_INFORMATION = {}; #global hash

sub someFunction() {
    my $key = 'name';
    my @storage = ();

    #assume file was properly opened here for the foreach-loop
    foreach my $line (<DATA>) {
        if(conditional) {
            my @ports = ();

            $storage[0] = 'banana';
            $storage[1] = \@ports;
            $storage[2] = '0';

            $DEVICE_INFORMATION{$key} = \@storage;      
        }

        elsif(conditional) {
            push @{$DEVICE_INFORMATION{$key}[1]}, 5;
        }
    }#end foreach
} #end someFunction
```

This is a simplified version of the code I am writing. I have a subroutine that I call in the main. It parses a very specifically designed file. That file *guarantees* that the if statement fires before subsequent elsif statement.

I think the push call in the elsif statement is not working properly - i.e. 5 is not being stored in the @ports array that should exist in the @storage array that should be returned when I hash the key into DEVICE_INFORMATION.

In the main I try and print out each element of the @storage array to check that things are running smoothly.

```
#main execution
&someFunction();

print $DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[0];
print $DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[1];
print $DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[2];
```

The output for this ends up being... banana ARRAY(blahblah) 0

If I change the print statement for the middle call to:

```
print @{$DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[1]};
```

Or to:

```
print @{$DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[1]}[0];
```

The output changes to banana [blankspace] 0

Please advise on how I can properly update the @ports array while it is stored inside the @storage array that has been hash'd into DEVICE_INFORMATION and then how I can access the elements of @ports. Many thanks!

P.S. I apologize for the length of this post. It is my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Please see the comments under the accepted answer for clarification as to why some of the proper code above was not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to tell you that [**`Data::Dumper`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) can help you sort out Perl data structures, but [**`Data::Dumper`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) can also tell you about your *first* problem:

Here's what happens when you sign open-curly + close-curly ( '{}' ) to a hash:

```
use Data::Dumper ();

my %DEVICE_INFORMATION = {}; #global hash
print Dumper->Dump( [ \%DEVICE_INFORMATION ], [ '*DEVICE_INFORMATION ' ] );
```

Here's the output:

```
%DEVICE_INFORMATION  = (
                         'HASH(0x3edd2c)' => undef
                       );
```

What you did is you assigned the *stringified* hash *reference* as a key to the list element that comes after it. *implied*

```
my %DEVICE_INFORMATION = {} => ();
```

So Perl assigned it a value of ***`undef`***.

When you assign to a hash, you assign a list. A literal empty hash is not a list, it's a *hash reference*. What you wanted to do for an *empty* hash--and what is totally unnecessary--is this:

```
my %DEVICE_INFORMATION = ();
```

And that's unnecessary because it is *exactly* the same thing as:

```
my %DEVICE_INFORMATION;
```

You're declaring a hash, and that statement fully identifies it as a hash. And Perl is not going to guess what you want in it, so it's an empty hash from the get-go.

Finally, my advice on using [**`Data::Dumper`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper). If you started your hash off right, and did the following:

```
my %DEVICE_INFORMATION; # = {}; #global hash    
my @ports = ( 1, 2, 3 );

# notice that I just skipped the interim structure of @storage
# and assigned it as a literal 
# * Perl has one of the best literal data structure languages out there.
$DEVICE_INFORMATION{name} = [ 'banana', \@ports, '0' ];
print Data::Dumper->Dump( 
      [ \%DEVICE_INFORMATION ]
    , [ '*DEVICE_INFORMATION' ] 
    );
```

What you see is:

```
%DEVICE_INFORMATION  = (
                         'name' => [
                                     'banana',
                                     [
                                       1,
                                       2,
                                       3
                                     ],
                                     '0'
                                   ]
                       );
```

So, you can better see how it's all getting stored, and what levels you have to deference and how to get the information you want out of it.

By the way, `Data::Dumper` delivers 100% runnable Perl code, and shows you how you can specify the same structure as a literal. One caveat, you would have to *declare* the variable first, using `strict` (which you should always use anyway).

Comment: Data::Dumper seems like a power tool. Thank you for bringing that to my attention.


Your answer leaves me a bit perplexed, however, as I cannot simply assign @ports in the manner you did. Due to the nature of parsing a file, I will first receive 'banana' and the two 0s. Only after that has been added to DEVICE_INFORMATION will I then get the ports information.

Your answer directly assigns ports and includes it in $D_I immediately. I am still left unsure how to dynamically add in an array after I have already hashed some information.

Comment: In what may be one of the more embarrassing mistakes I have made, I forgot to update my test file to trigger the "elsif" conditional. Data::Dumper is what brought it to my attention. Thank you kindly Axeman. Your information, and your help, is very much appreciated!

Comment: @CaptainRyan: I was just trying to have something in ports to show you what the dump of what you were trying to do would look like. It doesn't demonstrate how to assign the ports, but simulates the case of *having* a port array.

Answer (score -1):

You update @ports properly.
Your print statement accesses $storage[1] (reference to @ports) in wrong way.
You may use syntax you have used in `push`.

```
print $DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[0], ";",
      join( ':', @{$DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[1]}), ";",
      $DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[2], "\n";
print "Number of ports: ", scalar(@{$DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[1]})),"\n";
print "First port: ", $DEVICE_INFORMATION{'name'}[1][0]//'', "\n";
# X//'' -> X or '' if X is undef
```